# When do you use "a priori", and when "a fortiori" in a formal proof?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, terminology

I am not sure I understand whether the term "a priori" or "a fortiori" is needed in proofs of the following form:

"Let $(S, \circ)$ be a group.

Then because a group is defined as a semigroup with and identity and in which every element has an inverse, $(S, \circ)$ is also a semigroup."

... which I would like to replace with either

"Then $(S, \circ)$ is a fortiori a semigroup."

... or

"Then $(S, \circ)$ is a priori a semigroup."

I believe "a fortiori" is the correct one to use here, but is this technically correct?

And in what context *does* one use the other one?

Comment: No use at all in a "formal" proof... Of course, they can be used in a natural language text (also mathematical) with their current meaning.

Comment: @markvs i don't understand the question

Comment: The question should contain the context: what did you try, what are the difficulties, etc.

Comment: As they said in Rome, gutta cavat lapidem non vi, sed saepe cadendo.

Comment: @markvs Yes, I copied and pasted your last post into Google Translate, my own Latin education being some 4.5 decades rusty, but I remain bewildered. This is not a question for "trying stuff out" and encountering "difficulties", it is merely about help understanding what a concept means. Hence I believe that your second comment is of limited relevance to the question under consideration, and that your third comment may even be the product of mischief. But I welcome a less gnomic explanation of your thought processes to perhaps allay my bewilderment.

Comment: Yes, as the Roman's say, morituri te salutant. A-priori and a-fortiori.

Comment: @markvs Я считаю, что ваш комментарий предназначен для издевательства. Пожалуйста, ведите себя прилично.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is not to use words and phrases that you don't understand as you are likely to confuse your reader :)

That said; *a fortiori* is Latin for *with stronger reason* and so can be used anywhere you would use the English term.  The phrase *a priori* means *reasoning from what is prior (logically or chronologically)* and so can be used whenever you are referring back to things presented earlier in the proof.  Both of these definitions come directly from Chambers Dictionary which is generally a reliable resource for English.  (If you're in North America you may prefer something like the American Heritage Dictionary or Merriam-Webster.)

So, so you can use *a fortiori* as in your example: because $S$ is a group, which is a stronger structural requirement, it is *a fortiori* a semigroup.  In order to use *a priori* you would have had to have reasoned (i.e. proved) that any group is automatically a semigroup; then you could say that $S$ is *a priori* a semigroup.

Finally, it might be worth noting that neither of these expressions are terribly common in modern mathematics.  When writing, the aim is to communicate to the reader as clearly as possible, and if you don't know that your audience will know your Latin terms (100 years ago you could have taken that as a certainty) then it might be better to use plain English.

Comment: One reason I ask this question is that I found the terms in a dictionary of mathematics, and they are not so well explained therein. In order to be able to explain them myself, in case anyone asks me (as it is not inconceivable that they will) it is important for me to understand them too. Your explanation is lucid.